# Python isn't recognizing _sendkeys.c file when I try to run SendKeys.py

Tags: python, windows, sendkeys

I am attempting to run a script that incorperates SendKeys.py to present scanner signals into Matlab to simulate the timing environment of fMRI scanners. Right now, when I cd into the folder with all the python scripts and run SendKeys I get this error back:

```
    File C:\Python27\Scripts\SendKeys.py", line 16, in (module)
      from _sendkeys.c import char2keycode, key_up, key_down, toggle_numlock
    ImportError: No module named _sendkeys.c
```

The interesting thing is that this script is currently working fine on our lab's desktop, so my goal is to find the difference in path settings, file placement, or literally any other potential issue so this script works on the laptop too.

I have set as many paths as I can think of that would relate to python, I have downgraded my python version on my laptop to the version downloaded on my desktop that SendKeys works on, and I even copied the files being used on my desktop and emailed them to my laptop to ensure they are identical.

```
cd Python27/Scripts
python SendKeys.py
```

and the above error ensues

The output is supposed to present a 't' every x seconds on a different window (i.e. Matlab), but as of now its not doing that because of the ImportError

Comment: Does _sendkeys.c contain source code in the "C" programming language?  If so a Python interpreter does not know how to process that.

Comment: I believe so, I tried adding include "Python.h" to the top of _sendkeys.c, but that didn't solve the issue which likely isn't surprising. I'm fairly new to coding so I'm not really sure what I should and shouldn't try at the moment. Is there anything I can do so that Python can interpret it? Would turning the source code into object code help this?

Comment: p.s. Would it be possible to convert _sendkeys.c to python source code or would that likely interfere with its intended purpose?

Comment: They're two different programming languages.  The python interpreter cannot read C source code, period.  You need to run the C source code through a C compiler and linker, build it into a DLL and connect your python program to it with ctypes.  That's beyond your current ability level.  What does _sendkeys do?  Can you find a Python module that does the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the solution. I downloaded a C++ compiler for Microsoft Visual Studio here (http://aka.ms/vcpython27) and then redownloaded SendKeys.py by typing 'python setup.py install' into command prompt.